# strapi.JS GRAPHQL ERROR "Expected value of type \"StringFilterInput\", found \”anna\”.”,

Tags: graphql, strapi

I'm try GraphQL with strapi.JS and get error in http://localhost:1337/graphql

Very similar work well previously in other website. I'm try before changing other user nothing work.

Here full error:

```
    {
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Expected value of type \"StringFilterInput\", found \"ann.bystry\".",
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 2,
            "column": 58
          }
        ],
        "extensions": {
          "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED",
          "exception": {
            "stacktrace": [
              "GraphQLError: Expected value of type \"StringFilterInput\", found \"ann.bystry\".",
              "    at isValidValueNode (/Users/ann.bystry/annblogstry/node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/ValuesOfCorrectTypeRule.js:118:25)",
              "    at Object.StringValue (/Users/ann.bystry/annblogstry/node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/ValuesOfCorrectTypeRule.js:93:14)",
              "    at Object.enter (/Users/ann.bystry/annblogstry/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:323:29)",
              "    at Object.enter (/Users/ann.bystry/annblogstry/node_modules/graphql/utilities/TypeInfo.js:370:25)",
              "    at visit (/Users/ann.bystry/annblogstry/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:243:26)",
              "    at validate (/Users/ann.bystry/annblogstry/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:69:24)",
              "    at validate (/Users/ann.bystry/annblogstry/node_modules/apollo-server-koa/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:185:39)",
              "    at processGraphQLRequest (/Users/ann.bystry/annblogstry/node_modules/apollo-server-koa/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:90:34)",
              "    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)",
              "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)",
              "    at async processHTTPRequest (/Users/ann.bystry/annblogstry/node_modules/apollo-server-koa/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/runHttpQuery.js:183:30)",
              "    at async /Users/ann.bystry/annblogstry/node_modules/apollo-server-koa/dist/ApolloServer.js:82:59",
              "    at async bodyParser (/Users/ann.bystry/annblogstry/node_modules/koa-bodyparser/index.js:95:5)",
              "    at async cors (/Users/ann.bystry/annblogstry/node_modules/@koa/cors/index.js:98:16)",
              "    at async returnBodyMiddleware (/Users/ann.bystry/annblogstry/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/services/server/compose-endpoint.js:52:18)",
              "    at async policiesMiddleware (/Users/ann.bystry/annblogstry/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/services/server/policy.js:28:5)"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `StringFilterInput` type definition/structure?

Answer (score 4):

welcome to Stackoverflow, glad to see you are starting out with Strapi!

If I understand right, you are referring to V4, if you used V3 before, then as @xadm pointed out you likely are providing incorrect input for your GraphQL query filters.

You can always find the definition (the parameters it accepts and the format of them) for `StringFilterInput` and any other types by clicking on the green "DOCS" label on the right hand side of your GraphQL Playground (Screenshot below):

[image: GraphQL Strapi API Docs]

With this in mind you may want to try querying with the below query (replacing `posts` with the Collection Type you are searching for)

*also note the " `eq:`  in `username` filter

```
query {
  posts(filters: { author: { username: { eq: "ann.bystry" } } }) {
    data {
      id
      attributes {
        title
        # query other fields here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Friendly suggestion for future - when you ask a question it is always useful to paste in any relevant code samples and versions of the frameworks/packages you are using :)

Best of luck!